# Azure table storage: DataServiceClientException - "The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met."

Tags: azure-table-storage

we have just deployed an Azure App and are getting these errors when updating an object in TableStorage?

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code sample?
Which language are you .NET?

Anyhow, you most likely didn't complete or have an error in the HTTP request header.

Possible problem:

- Content-Length not the good value
- Content-Type not set
- Authentification header missing
- If-Match:* missing in case of an update/merge/delete

Comment: Take a look at MSDN Status code : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179382.aspx